# How to manage cpu intense task on electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am developing a desktop app with Electron and Angular 7.

There is a part where I need to zip a folder, which could weight a lot.
I am using ipcRenderer to send from angular to electron the signal to start the zipping.
This is the chunk of the ipcMain:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const zip = require('file-zip');

...

ipcMain.on('zip', (event, args) => {
  const { from, to } = args;
  zip.zipFolder(from, to, (error) => {
    event.sender.send('zip-response', error);
  });
});
```

The problem is that when the folder has a huge size, the task takes a lot and blocks the rendered process.

I have already tried with **'electron-remote'** and its method **requireTaskPool**, like this:

```
const zip = require('file-zip');
function zipDir(from, to) {
    zip.zipFolder(from, to, (error) => {
        return error;
    });
}
module.exports = zipDir;
```

and:

```
import { requireTaskPool } from 'electron-remote';
const zip = requireTaskPool(require.resolve('./zip'));

ipcMain.on('zip', (event, args) => {
  const { from, to } = args;
  zip(from, to).then(error => event.sender.send('zip-response', error));
});
```

but it did not work, "zip" always resolved immediately, without executing the zip function, probably because zip.zipFolder uses a callback.

Any idea?

Comment: Don't you want to call `zip.zipFolder(from, to)` instead of `zip(from, to)`?